# iTextSharp - I cannot use tabs in PDF. Lists do not replicate want I need

Tags: itext

I am attempting to create a PDF document that looks like this one. It uses a lot of tabs to indicate list levels and other documents like it could use custom enumerations.

http://mgaleg.maryland.gov/2018RS/Statute_Web/gab/1-101.pdf
I cannot seem to add a tab to a paragraph using \t.

I tried using lists but I need custom enumeration. I also need only the first line to indent.

For example I cannot create the following without tabs.

§1-101.
       (a)     In this article In this article the following words have the meanings indicated.

```
   (b)     (1)     Some other language that wraps but is aligned to the left margin if we go to another line.

           (2)     Some other text.
```

The iTextSharp code that utilizes lists will not wrap to the left margin on the next line like I need and I need to control exactly what the enumerators are. They might be (A-1) or any other way the author wants to create the document.

edit:

I upgraded to iText 7 in .Net.
I used the following code that got me closer to what I am looking for.

```
        String dest = "c:\\temp\\abc.pdf";

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.Add("Article - Alcoholic Beverages");
        p.SetFont(font);
        p.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);   
        doc.Add(p);


        p = new Paragraph();
        p.Add("§1-101.");
        p.SetFont(font);
        doc.Add(p).SetFont(font);

        p = new Paragraph();
        p.SetFirstLineIndent(25);
        p.AddTabStops(new TabStop(1f, TabAlignment.LEFT));
        p.Add("(a)");
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("In this article the following words have the meanings indicated.");
        doc.Add(p).SetFont(font);

        p = new Paragraph();
        p.SetFirstLineIndent(25);
        p.AddTabStops(new TabStop(1f, TabAlignment.LEFT));
        p.Add("(b)");
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("(1)");
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("“Alcoholic beverage” means a spirituous, vinous, malt, or fermented liquor, liquid, or compound that: ");
        doc.Add(p).SetFont(font);

        p = new Paragraph();
        p.SetFirstLineIndent(25);
        p.AddTabStops(new TabStop(1f, TabAlignment.LEFT));
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("(i)");
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("contains at least one–half of 1% of alcohol by volume; and");
        doc.Add(p).SetFont(font);

        p = new Paragraph();
        p.SetFirstLineIndent(25);
        p.AddTabStops(new TabStop(1f, TabAlignment.LEFT));
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("(ii)");
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("is suitable for beverage purposes.");
        doc.Add(p).SetFont(font);

        p = new Paragraph();
        p.SetFirstLineIndent(25);
        p.AddTabStops(new TabStop(1f, TabAlignment.LEFT));
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("(2)");
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("“Alcoholic beverage” includes alcohol, brandy, whiskey, rum, gin, cordial, beer, and wine.");
        doc.Add(p).SetFont(font);

        p = new Paragraph();
        p.SetFirstLineIndent(25);
        p.AddTabStops(new TabStop(1f, TabAlignment.LEFT));
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("(3)");
        p.Add(new Tab()); p.Add("“Alcoholic beverage” does not include a confectionery food product that contains up to 5 % of alcohol by volume and is regulated by the Maryland Department of Health under § 21–209 of the Health – General Article.");
        doc.Add(p).SetFont(font);

        doc.Close();
```

Comment: Show us your code, but before you do so, please be aware that there is no such things as "tabs" in ISO 32000 (aka the PDF specification). If you are just converting strings with `\t` characters to PDF, then you clearly didn't read the documentation. Tab functionality in iText 7 is explained in the [building blocks tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-3). Also note that **there are no tabs** in the document you refer to; all text is added at absolute positions (no `\t` involved). You might update your question because what you say is incorrect.

Comment: Moreover: I see that you are still using the old name **iTextSharp.** Please note that we changed the name 2 years ago: since iText 7, we talk about iText for .NET, *not* about iTextSharp. Maybe you're still using an old version.

Comment: Bruno. Thank you for the response. I am  new to using iText but not entirely. I've used it to do minor things over the years. It was my understanding it was a Java port and that was how it was referred to. After looking at the NuGet package I pulled in I'm using version 5.5.13. 
As for tabs in the document. The document is originally created in MS Word and converted to XML then I want to convert the XML to PDF documents to replace another product. I'm evaluating if iText can handle the formatting. I'll look into the tab setting and take another shot at the product once I get on the latest ver

Comment: I was able to upgrade to iText 7 and make some code changes and made some progress to do what I wanted. I am still figuring out the tabstops as they might be more space than I would like. I'll include my code for consideration or for anyone who might be interested.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I cannot figure out how to post the code.